# comparison to get only lines with changed values on a column

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, csv

Given the following two csv files, previously sorted:

**file1**

```
a,1,val1
b,2,val2
c,3,val3
d,4,val4
e,5,val5
f,6,val6
g,7,val7
```

**file2**

```
a,1,val1
b,2,val2
c,3,val3x
e,5,val5x
g,7,val7
h,8,val8
```

How can I compare and get only the lines that changed the value on the 3rd column? I'm expecting to get something like this:

```
c,3,val3x
e,5,val5x
```

I must ignore equal, added or deleted lines, I just care about modified lines. I'd prefer to use linux native commands, no pearl, python, etc. I need to process files with tens of millions of lines at work so I'm looking something with good performance.
I tried using `diff -U 0` but I guess is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Homework? Interview question? Its usually considered polite to mention.

Comment: I need to process some csv files at work but I don't want to write a script for that, I want to simplify it on a single command if possible

Answer (score 1):

How about awk?

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3; next} ($1,$2) in a && $3 != a[$1,$2]' file1 file2
c,3,val3x
e,5,val5x
```

---

If you need to handle advanced CSV features (in particular, embedded commas in quoted CSV fields, which a simple `awk -F,` won't deal with) then there's always the Python-based csvkit suite of tools. In particular you could use `csvsql`:

```
$ csvsql -H --query '
    SELECT file2.* FROM file1 INNER JOIN file2 ON file1.a = file2.a AND file1.b = file2.b 
    WHERE file1.c != file2.c
  ' file1 file2 2>/dev/null
a,b,c
c,3,val3x
e,5,val5x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a sed-grep pipeline:

```
$ sed -e 's/$/x/' file1 | grep -xFf - file2
c,3,val3x
e,5,val5x
```

Notes:-

- First prepare the file1 data for being searched against data in file2
- `-x` => full line match and not a partial match
- `-F` => is for string match and not regex match
- `-f` => file contains strings to be looked for